# Loading local stylesheet and disabling specific linked stylesheets in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For the development process of some 3rd party integrations, I find it would be extremely useful if you were able to disable specific stylesheets and load a local stylesheet that you could then selectively reload, but I'm coming up short-handed.

I'm having a difficult time believing nobody else has tackled this issue, so I'm hoping one of you has a method or knows of a chrome extension available to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the form of the Chrome extension [Personalized Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personalized-web/plcnnpdmhobdfbponjpedobekiogmbco). By telling it to match my test environment and giving it the rules to remove specific link tags with specific style attributes and injecting an html tag to link to my localhost to deliver my custom stylesheet.

It would be great if there were a more streamlined solution, but of all the extensions available, this was the only one that did precisely what I needed it to.

I hope this helps someone else.